# bug which makes me enter data twice

Tags: java

I'm not sure why, but when I execute this code, I have to enter a number twice before the code will move on to the next piece, while it should only need to be entered once.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        double l;  //length
        double w;  //width
        double p;  //perimeter
        double a;  //area
        boolean r = true;
        boolean run = true;
        System.out.print("Please Enter the Length of the Rectangle: ");
        do {
            l = scanner.nextDouble();
            if (!(scanner.hasNextDouble())) {
                System.out.println("Please Enter A Number");
                scanner.next();
            } else if (l <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Please Enter a Number Which Is Greater Than 0");
                scanner.next();
            } else {
                double length = l;
                System.out.print("Please Enter the Width of the Rectangle: ");
                w = reader.nextDouble();
                if (!(reader.hasNextDouble())) {
                    System.out.println("Please Enter A Number");
                    reader.next();
                    run = true;
                } else if (w <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please Enter a Number Which Is Greater Than 0");
                    reader.next();
                    run = true;
                } else {
                    double width = w;
                    r = false;
                }
                a = l * w;
                p = (2 * l) + (2 * w);
                System.out.println("The Area of the Rectangle is " + a);
                System.out.println("The Perimeter of the Rectangle is " + p);
                run = false;
                break;
            }
        } while (run);
    }
}
```

Comment: which line is it happening on? the very first scanner? `l = scanner.nextDouble();`? Also your do-while logic is strange, you have `run = false;` and then `while(run)` If you only want the code to run once why do you even have a do-while loop?

Comment: Why are you creating two scanners on the same input source?

Answer (score 0):

`scanner.hasNextDouble` waits to have some input in the buffer if it is empty. So you are waiting twice (first time for `nextDouble` and second time for `hasNextDouble`)

You can change your code to something like :

```
if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    l = Double.parseDouble(scanner.next());
    ......
}
else {
   // ERROR...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what `hasNextDouble()` do

Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as a double value using the `nextDouble()` method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

so it calls `nextDouble()` to check if there is a double in the scanner,
and `nextDouble()` will wait for System.in.

so you need to remove the `hasNextDouble()` and check the values of l and w after `nextDouble()`

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a double and AFTER IT asking if its another double.

Fix changing it that way:

```
if(!(scanner.hasNextDouble()))
    {
       ....
    }
l = scanner.nextDouble();
```

Comment: I think it will also wait twice with the code you posted.

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't wait twice. But also I can't understand why he's using 2 different scanners....

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is calling either `scanner.nextDouble()` or `scanner.next()` will wait for user input, so you don't want to call both when you want just the one input read.

What you want to do is create a helper method `getNextPositiveDouble()` that will handle the bad user input, loop until it gets a valid input, and then return you a positive value. This way you don't mess up your main programme logic and it is easier to reason with (think clean code).

So lets break this down.

How can we loop infinitely until we get a Double from the Scanner?

```
while(!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    System.out.println("Please Enter A Number");
    scanner.next();
}
```

Given that has executed, how can we then validate that the Double is positive?

```
Double temp = scanner.nextDouble();

if(temp <= 0) {
    System.out.println("Please Enter a Number Which Is Greater Than 0");
}
```

Obviously we need to loop until we get a positive value so let's put the two code snippets together into the helper function

```
private static Double getNextPositiveDouble(Scanner scanner) {

    Double dbl = null;

    while(dbl == null) {
        while(!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter A Number");
            scanner.next();
        }

        Double temp = scanner.nextDouble();

        if(temp <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Number Which Is Greater Than 0");
        }
        else {
            dbl = temp;
        }
    }

    return dbl;
}
```

Now your existing code just has to call this method like this, and you can reuse the helper method for your other inputs that also require a positive double value.

```
...
System.out.print("Please Enter the Length of the Rectangle: ");
do {
    l = getNextPositiveDouble(scanner);
    ...
```